# How to build boost using Intel Compiler

Tags: visual-c++, boost, compiler-construction, intel

How i can build boost lib's for x86 platforms and plus Windows XP support using Intel Compiler 14? Also i have installed MSVC 2010/2013 on my PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boost it built by running `bjam` (or `b2`, they are the same). In your case you have to make sure you specify `toolset=intel`. For example,

```
c:\boost-dir> bootstrap.bat
c:\boost-dir> bjam install toolset=intel variant=debug link=static threading=multi runtime-link=static
```

Comment: i have some problems with it. Example http://prntscr.com/2rwymk.

i think i must setup environment variables. Like in this thread: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/building-boost-with-intel-c-composer-xe-2013-on-windows-7

but this is for x64 and i need for x32 architecture.

Thanks

Comment: @user922871 Yes, but I think another set of vars maybe more applicable. Can you locate and run `iclvars_ia32.bat` under your compiler program files dir? Are you building for 64 or 32 bit?